# What's the advantage of NASA's flying saucer over traditional aerodynamic models?

Tags: aerodynamics, space-mission

NASA has recently [tested a saucer-shaped spaceship](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2014/02jun_saucer/). What's the advantage of this new design over traditional aerodynamic designs?

The test launch was performed from within atmosphere which would offer higher air drag. What's the positive side of this that this big thing has been ignored?

Comment: Are you speaking about Orion space capsule?

Comment: It does not look so different from traditional reentry vehicles (see Soyouz/Shenzhou reentry capsule, Curiosity atmospheric entry shell, ...)

Comment: Currently they go from 1) a small aeroshell to 2) a large parachute. They want something in between, a 1.5

Comment: Well the martians have been harassing us with flying saucers for decades. I think NASA is just trying to even the score a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the article. I also think that the name 'Flying Saucer' is a bit misleading. I think referring to it with the actual project name: 'Low Density Supersonic Decelerator' (LDSD) fits better. The concept of this project is that a spacecraft uses a inflatable saucer-shaped balloon to increase its reference area (the surface area used in the [drag equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation)) to increase its atmospheric drag during [atmospheric entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_entry).

During NASA's test flight they want to test whether this system would suffice to land big spacecrafts safely on to Mars. To simulate the atmosphere of Mars they lift the test craft with a helium balloon high up into the atmosphere of Earth such that the density is similar to that of Mars at its surface. They than use a rocket to get up to speeds comparable with a atmospheric entry at Mars. [This video](http://youtu.be/kwEXCopRwsA?t=1m46s) also gives a good explanation of the LDSD, and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOsAlfQ2DoQ) give a little longer and more detailed explanation.

Comment: Wasn't the similar thing used in Curiosity (during atmosphere reentry)? Why the buzz then?

Comment: @SachinShekhar Curiosity used a normal non-inflatable heatshield. This LDSD will be able to increase its diameter by inflating its shield. I added a second link to a video which shows this better.

Answer (score 0):

The atmosphere of Mars is far thinner than ours. The current problem in landing anything (popularly knows as [7 minutes of terror](http://www.businessinsider.com/nasa-mars-rover-7-minutes-of-terror-2012-8?IR=T)) in which any module (curiosity for now) had to decelerate from 13,000 MPH to 0 MPH in 7 minutes.

I **did not** read the entire page you have linked to,but on the very top it says 
"To test a new technology for landing heavy payloads on Mars, NASA is about to drop a flying-saucer shaped vehicle from a helium balloon high above Earth's surface."

And as far as it appears for now the higher the air drag the better it is for a "Mars lander" provided there is sufficient thermal insulation.

Comment: Higher the air drag better doesn’t look compatible with Mars has thinner atmosphere.

Comment: For any atmosphere you need as much air drag as possible if you have to decelerate from a speed of 13,000 MPH to 0 in a few minutes. The required air drag on Mars would result in designs that would give unbelievable high magnitude air drag on earth.

Comment: Curiosity atmospheric reentry shell offered the similar drag too. Then, why sacrifice aerodynamic benefits in Earth atmosphere?

Comment: The shell is inflatable, so it will only have the highest drag/surface area when it reaches Mars.